# Wordpress субдиректория у урле и папке

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, nginx

Добрый день.

Ситуация вроде бы рядовая, но почему-то не могу найти толковой информации по вопросу.

Собственно, WP поставил в example.com/blog, на example.com другое двигло.
Лежит отдельная папка blog в корне, тоже самое в урле /blog.

Установка прошла успешно, все ок. по адресу example.com/blog/wp-admin админка все нормально.

Но стоит открыть любую страницу, любой другой вложенный урл, например example.com/blog/page-1/ то показывается просто 404 основного двигла.

Мысли такие: либо править что-то в .htaccess корня, либо править nginx.conf.

В принципе логично - указанные настройки пропускают в example.com/blog - потому что это реально существующая папка в которой лежит index.php - а дальше он все принимает и обрабатывает.

А вот если example.com/blog/page-1/ - то по этому адресу страницы нет, и поэтому происходит стандартная обработка. А должно быть так что: ага, это в подпапке значит обращаться к example.com/blog/index.php , а обращение очевидно идет к example.com/index.php

Собственно, с wp-admin - точно такая же ситуация. Существует физический файл по адресу example.com/blog/wp-admin/index.php - поэтому идет обработка.

Возможно, так же что косяк и с blog/.htaccess. Но я больше грешу в сторону общих настроек nginx. Например.

```
 location / {
        try_files       $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
                index  index.html index.htm index.php;
        }
```

Собственно, справка здесь - https://codex.wordpress.org/Nginx
Но она написана под домен целиком. А мне в принципе нужно было бы попробовать как: оставить все настройки для сайта-корня, но вот для подпапки дать другие, WP-шные настройки обработки. Как это сделать мне непонятно пока.

Answer (score 1):

Сделал вот так и все заработало:

```
 location /blog {
           try_files       $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;
           index  index.html index.htm index.php;

 }

 location / {
            try_files       $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
            index  index.html index.htm index.php;
 }
```

В общем не знаю, как насчет того, что не все правила WP для nginx я заиспользовал. Например, обращение к .php я не трогал, поскольку в общих правилах есть уже "что-то" на этот счет.